# Can I disable MultipleActiveResultSets in my codebase without consequences?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

We found we're qualifiying for the issue described at https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/422 : linux machines querying SqlServer using a connectionString where `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` and having exceptions alike

```
---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): Unknown error 258
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
```

A bunch of services all have MARS set to True, which I'd like to disable (set to False).
It is unclear to me what consequences this has on a current codebase. I have searched around and found that it transparently adds performance wins (in a scenario where the client is windows-based, that is), but was unable to find dependencies of MARS using sql.

Can I disable MARS without consequences to my current application?

Comment: If you don't need to have multiple active result sets then you can disable MARS. If you're not using it, you don't need it enabled.

Comment: It's not generally possible to divine if your code depends on MARS just by a cursory glance, or even general code patterns. As the name implies, MARS enables the use of multiple active result sets on a single connection. If MARS is required by the code, it won't work if it's turned off. Usually code that needs MARS will use it prominently in the main code path, so it should become obvious fairly quickly if turned off and tested, but it's of course not a 100% guarantee -- a service may be implicitly and unnecessarily relying on MARS only in a less used code path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MARS primarily impacts scenarios where you have an *open, in progress reader*, and you execute a second command on the same connection. This could be for N+1 operations. So: you need to review for any time where you open a reader and then do something (anything) on the connection before the reader is closed/disposed. If you never do that: you can disable MARS.

Assuming you have decent tests and/or a test environment, you can just disable MARS and see what happens!

Enabling MARS does not, AFAIK, add transparent/automatic performance wins - and having the machinery in place to *support* overlapping operations could actually result in a very minor performance hit when enabled, when it isn't being exploited.

Comment: I think that the OP actually meant that setting it to `false` would "transparently add[..] performance wins" as that's the change they're contemplating, which would gel with your statement.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ah, yes, I agree that the statement can be read in two ways - but either way, I think I've covered the intent :)